# dynamically add images from a folder

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way using either html or javascript or anything else,to add all the images present in a folder to the webpage.

Suppose i have 10 images then instead of writing ten lines of code like

```
<img src="1.jpg"/>
<img src="2.jpg"/>
.
.
.
```

etc

just a single line of code which could add all images from a folder like "*.jpg" all jpg images. I'm new to web technologies, and just got such doubt.

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks and best Regards

Comment: The problem with JS is it is client side, and to retrieve the files in a folder you will need to have some sort of index which will have to be generated server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said "or anything else" I would recommend using a bash one-liner for collecting images in the current folder and add them to a single file, named **index.html**:

```
for i in *.jpg; do echo "<img src='$i' />" >> index.html; done;
```

Just add the missing html-tags and done.

EDIT: You can use the Windows shell (cmd) as well:

```
FOR %i IN (*.JPG) DO ECHO ^<img src="%i" /^> >> index.html
```

Comment: wow, but what language is it. and i need to merge this without writing <script> tag.

Comment: As I stated it is written for the bash shell. You could use this code if you have access to a bash shell either on the server or on your own computer. In the latter case you could run this line and edit the resulting file before loading it up to your webserver. The advantage of this solution (as well as any other server-side solution involving e.g. php, perl, python, ruby etc.) lies in the fact that no browser visiting your page has to have javascript support enabled.

Comment: yah, thats good solution. But i'm using bash in windows and the index.html file contains just "<img src='*.jpg' />"

Comment: can anybody add their thoughts to this approach. I think this could be more closer to what i need. But the output is not as expected. Just one line of <img> tag is being generated here. Thanks

Comment: I added a simple solution for the windows shell. It worked on my Windows Vista box. Maybe this helps – since I don't know why the bash version didn't work for you ...

Comment: This is simply great.. It worked for me as well. Also i have tried to add that script in a bat file and execute but dint work. How to add it to a bat file?? Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding the bat file: Sorry, but I don't know. I am not using Windows regularly and especially not the shell. Maybe someone else can help?

Answer (score 5):

In HTML - no.

But, if all images are named as "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"... so you can build a javascript loop.

try something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
document.write("<img src=\"" + i + ".jpg\"/>");
document.write("<br />");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Read here: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_loop_for.asp
,and try learning basic programming issues, just as looping..

Comment: this one works great,but the file names have to 1,2... Isn't there any other way using javascript which can display any number of images and having any name. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to do this with a server-side technology, such as PHP with its [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function and [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Comment: ok. I dont know php, so is there any not so easier way using javascript or html??

Comment: the php solution seems to be better,coz it doesn't depend on the file names.But can you tell the sample implementation with jpg files. Thanks

Comment: There's an example on the page linked. Just replace `*.txt` with `*.jpg`.

Comment: hey i've tried using glob function but all in vain. Can you help me with it, how exactly and what piece of code actually does it.. I could not understand it properly. Thanks

Comment: here is ur answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129086/how-to-display-images-from-a-folder-using-php-php