# How to display images from a folder using php - PHP

Tags: php

It would be great if someone could help me figure out why the browser cannot load the images (error 404). The code works, and the image source is correct, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. (using localhost)

```
$dir          = '/home/user/Pictures';
$file_display = array(
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png',
    'gif'
);

if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
    echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
} else {
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
        $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

        if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
            echo '<img src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so why don't you post the code?

Comment: Just did. Forgot to indent.

Comment: there are syntax errors on the code above like in_array( does not have the closing parenthesis. the $ char in the echo

Comment: someone needs to learn basic syntax

Comment: assuming the syntax error are corrected, the problem why is not showing is because the /home/user/pictures may not be serve by the web server because it not a web directory unless it set on the apache config file

Comment: @user2837048 Try a relative path instead of absolute.

Comment: @user2837048 Run your script from the root of your server and change this `$dir = '/home/user/Pictures';` to `$dir = 'Pictures';` and your images will show up. However,  you may get the error message `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in...` --- I don't quite know why I'm getting that error but your code works, to a certain extent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had a mistake on the statement below. Use . not ,

```
echo '<img src="', $dir, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, $
```

to

```
echo '<img src="'. $dir. '/'. $file. '" alt="'. $file. $
```

and

```
echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
```

to

```
echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found!';
```

Comment: actually for echo statement comma can be used instead of the concat operator

Comment: the comma actually has better performance compared to . on echo statements

Comment: string concatenation is memory intensive

Comment: @user2837048, have you corrected the syntax errors from your code?

Comment: Yes, I did, as you can tell.

Comment: can you update the above script the code without syntax errors

Comment: try accessing 1 image file directly like this: http:/localhost/home/user/Pictures/pic1.jpg (i dont think you can because /home/user/pictures is not accessible via web access)

Comment: unless you tell the webserver to do so, in apache this can be done on the httpd.conf

Comment: there a couple of options 1. Place the pictures folder into your apps directory, 2. configure web server to allow web access to the /home/user/pictures directory 3. create a separate script file that will stream each image from non web-accessible directory

Comment: the first option is simplest, but if its not possible you should choose 2 or 3

Comment: if for you cannot move pictures to your app directory, and you will not allow web access to this folder then option 3 is the only solution

Answer (score 9):

Here is a possible solution the solution #3 on my comments to blubill's answer:

```
yourscript.php
========================
<?php
    $dir = '/home/user/Pictures';
    $file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    if (file_exists($dir) == false) 
    {
        echo 'Directory "', $dir, '" not found!';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $dir_contents = scandir($dir);

        foreach ($dir_contents as $file) 
        {
            $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
            if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true)     
            {
                $name = basename($file);
                echo "<img src='img.php?name={$name}' />";
            }
        }
    }
?>


img.php
========================
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $mimes = array
    (
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $name)));

    $file = '/home/users/Pictures/'.$name;
    header('content-type: '. $mimes[$ext]);
    header('content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'";');
    readfile($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways to do that:

METHOD 1. The secure way.

Put the images on /www/htdocs/

```
<?php
    $www_root = 'http://localhost/images';
    $dir = '/var/www/images';
    $file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    if ( file_exists( $dir ) == false ) {
       echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
    } else {
       $dir_contents = scandir( $dir );

        foreach ( $dir_contents as $file ) {
           $file_type = strtolower( end( explode('.', $file ) ) );
           if ( ($file !== '.') && ($file !== '..') && (in_array( $file_type, $file_display)) ) {
              echo '<img src="', $www_root, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '"/>';
           break;
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

METHOD 2. Unsecure but more flexible.

Put the images on any directory (apache must have permission to read the file).

```
<?php
    $dir = '/home/user/Pictures';
    $file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    if ( file_exists( $dir ) == false ) {
       echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
    } else {
       $dir_contents = scandir( $dir );

        foreach ( $dir_contents as $file ) {
           $file_type = strtolower( end( explode('.', $file ) ) );
           if ( ($file !== '.') && ($file !== '..') && (in_array( $file_type, $file_display)) ) {
              echo '<img src="file_viewer.php?file=', base64_encode($dir . '/' . $file), '" alt="', $file, '"/>';
           break;
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

And create another script to read the image file.

```
<?php
    $filename = base64_decode($_GET['file']);
    // Check the folder location to avoid exploit
    if (dirname($filename) == '/home/user/Pictures')
        echo file_get_contents($filename);
?>
```

Comment: considering the first method I think the "break" statement and checking if the ending of the file is "." or ".." are unnecessary unless I missed something, then would like to know what.