# Why My images are not shown in the webpage

Tags: php

I'm completely new to PHP and I'm writing a page which displays some images from my hard drive.
I've tried different syntaxes and none of them worked out for me ...

I've tested

```
echo '<img src="/var/www/netbeans/PhpProject2/Plate.jpg" alt ="Test" />';
```

and It didn't show anything for me .... I've tested this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129086/how-to-display-images-from-a-folder-using-php-php) Also and it didn't worked for me too, I've attached My monitor screen page below. as you can see it seems that my images are not found. I've pasted every address of my images in my browser separately and I was able to see them but when I add them in src argument of img function I'm not able to see them!

What do you think might be the source of problem .... I need to work on a project which needs to be fast enough in working with images.. what do you think I should use ? is "

[image]

Comment: you cannot display images from "your hard drive". it has be to served by your web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `/var/www`. Path should be the http path not the file physical path.

```
echo '<img src="/netbeans/PhpProject2/Plate.jpg" alt ="Test" />';
```

Comment: Yeah !!! so the problem lies in the localhost removal !!!! thank you I'll hit the answer button in the next few minutes ... Just one more question what's the best site to find useful functions for image manipulation (resize display in tables and ....) ?