# PHP/HTML - Trying to make image appear using localhost

Tags: php, html, image

I am using XAMPP for APACHE server on localhost:8080 (I had to change the default port for it to work). Assume that I have the rest of the html needed to run.
Here is the current code:

**home.html**

```
<body>
<script src="main/profile.php"></script>
</body>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
$imagepath ="omj/logo.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $imagepath);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

I tried referencing the following articles to no avail:

http://www.configure-all.com/howto_display_image.php

[How to display images from a folder using php - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129086/how-to-display-images-from-a-folder-using-php-php)

**Edit**
I got the image to work using HTML by simply moving the image folder inside the html folder. Now the question remains, why isn't the php code running to show the image?

The image path is within the directory of the html file. Like this: /htmlfolder/imagefolder/image.jpg while html file is /htmlfolder/file.html

Comment: Apparently it is a priority for some to cast down votes instead of giving the answer. I'm still not sure how to set this up. Akitha_MJ's answer did not work thus far.

Comment: Why is the src of your script a php file? You seem to have a misunderstanding of how php works.

Comment: I'm running a PHP script that shows the image.

Comment: You can't run a php script like that. Php is a server side language but the script tag is for client side code. Generally you would put JavaScript in a script tag.

Comment: So how do I do it? Every website has a different way to do the same thing. One website used the script tag. Now I'm bewildered enough to post it on this website, hoping that someone actually knows how to do it properly.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the website that used a script tag?

Comment: https://www.impressivewebs.com/php-file-html-script-tag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An html file cannot run php code.

Change your file name from home.html to home.php.

Then change this line:

```
<script src="main/profile.php"></script>
```

to

```
<?php echo '<img src="omj/logo.jpg"/>'; ?>
```

Comment: The thing is that I have to leave it as HTML, the rest of the code is using HTML and I just want to run the picture through PHP.

Comment: Why do you have to leave it as html?

Comment: In short, the webpage is structured as html. I don't know if it is possible to do all of the structuring in PHP, although I would like to do it that way.

Comment: Php can use html. You can leave the page as it is but just change the file extension to .php

Comment: Am I better off just leaving it in HTML for now? I suppose I could do it just to move on and learn more before doing something complicated like that, but there isn't a lot of documentation on PHP. The official PHP documentation looks just as confusing as Java API.

Comment: What is your goal? If your goal is to just display an image, you only need html for that. You can just use an img  tag for that.

Comment: I would suggest googling 'php hello world tutorial' and getting a basic php page set up first

Answer (score 0):

So simple, " PHP optimally used single quotes '. Use standard html within string!

```
echo ' <img src="php.gif" /> ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php $input = '<img src="/image/your.jpg" title="you are title " alt="any"/>'; $sx = simplexml_load_string($input); var_dump($sx); ?>
```

Comment: it doesn't load in html document and opening the php document shows a bunch of text:
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["src"]=> string(13) "/omj/logo.jpg" ["title"]=> string(14) "you are title " ["alt"]=> string(3) "any" } }

Comment: I used the whole line above.

Comment: Are you sure to use single quotes in $input? I would think that it would not parse the string to do what we want.

Answer (score 0):

As I said use with a variable like below

```
<?php 
$image_url='images/your.png';
?>

<img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">
```

Comment: Close! I have a broken image sign. I'm double checking the spelling.

Comment: Okay then check the link to image

Comment: Nothing yet, is there something I have to do with permissions of the folders or configuration settings with APACHE/XAMPP?

Comment: Are you using Linux distro

Comment: XAMPP/APACHE through Windows 10 Home. It runs the rest of the code properly (i.e. background image, text, CSS, etc.).

Comment: Then normally no problem occurs with permission